# ng new error: Could not find an NgModule for the new component - angular-cli

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli

Whenever I try create a new `angular-cli` project with command `ng new my-dream-app` I get the error :

```
Error: Could not find an NgModule for the new component. Use the skip-import option to skip importing components in NgModule.
Could not find an NgModule for the new component. Use the skip-import option to skip importing components in NgModule.
```

I even removed Nodejs, npm, npm-cache and node_modules folders wherever I found :)

```
Windows: 10
Nodejs : 8.10.0
npm    : 5.6.0
```

It should be noted that it's been working till last month.

**Update:**

```
Angular CLI: 1.7.3
Node: 8.10.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular:
...
```

Comment: Could you copy the output of ng --version please?

Comment: @SamiAl90 I updated my question, please take a look.

Comment: Please try this approach [stackoverflow.com/a/53696599/2668045](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53696599/2668045) Should be ok.